# How to implement a Trie Iterator with Thread run()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, trie

I have an uni assignment where I need to implement a `Trie` and it's nodes(`Node`) and the iterator.

The iterator should iterate over the nodes using a `StringBuffer` to maintain the status of the word and it should implement the `Runnable` interface, meaning I have to implement a `run()` method!

I have tried this implementation:

```java
class NodeIterator implements Iterator<String>, Runnable {
    String nextWord;
    boolean terminated;
    Thread thread;

    public NodeIterator() {
        thread = new Thread(this,"Node iterator");
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        terminated = false;

        visit(Trie.this.root);

        synchronized (this) {
            terminated = true;
            handshake();
        }
    }

    private void visit(Node node) {

    }

    private void handshake() {
        notify();

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if(!terminated)
                handshake();
        }

        return nextWord != null;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        String word = nextWord;

        synchronized (this) {
            word = null;
        }

        return word;
    }
}
```

I am missing an implementation for the `visit()` method as I'm not sure how to "visit" the nodes and I'm not sure the rest is correct as I've never worked with threads.

Should I be doing something differently?

Edit:

```
public class Trie implements Iterable<String> {
    Node root;

    ...

    private static class Node {
        private HashMap<Character, Node> children;
        private boolean endOfWord;

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is stored in the trie nodes?

Comment: @Joni I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can implement `visit()` is with recursion. The recursive method needs to keep track of the prefix of the string built so far, and if it finds a node that ends a word, publishes the string it has found so far. Assuming you can't change the signature for `visit(Node)`, you'll need a helper method:

```
    void visit(Node root) {
        visitRecursive("", root);
    }

    private void visitRecursive(String prefix, Node node) {
        if (node.endOfWord) {
            nextWord = prefix;
            synchronized (this) {
                handshake();
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Node> entry : node.children.entrySet()) {
            visitRecursive(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure all your multithreading code is correct, but the very least this will iterate over all strings stored in the trie.